# How to access a parent window from inside a page-object page-section?

Tags: watir, page-object-gem

Is there a way to access a parent page of a page-section from within a modal dialog box on the page-section?

Using Watir/PageObject, on a JS modal window, I can access content inside the modal as below.

```
dialog_box = ModalDialogBox.new @browser
dialog_box.modal_dialog do
  button.click
end
dialog_box.attach_to_window(title: browser.title)
dialog_box.add_data_to_form
dialog_box.click_save_button
```

When creating a modal dialog using the above method from inside a page-section, I get the below error as the page-section is no longer a window. App has lots of multi-level dialog boxes (i.e., modal dialogs spawning from a modal dialog)

> NoMethodError: undefined method `window' for Watir::Div:0x0000000481e7b0

Is there a way to access the original browser window to attach a modal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an Element, you can get it's browser using the `#browser` method:

```
your_element.browser
#=> Watir::Browser
```

If you need the window, you could call `#window` on that:

```
your_element.browser.window
#=> Watir::Window
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I was able to access the parent window page object by adding another .browser method.

    dialog_box = ModalDialogBox.new @browser.browser
    dialog_box.modal_dialog do
      button.click
    end
    dialog_box.attach_to_window(title: @browser.browser.title)
    dialog_box.add_data_to_form
    dialog_box.click_save_button